# Node.js, How to get JSON elemet from some url which i have to enter username and password in it?

Tags: node.js, json, url, http-status-code-403

> I use this function:

```
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var status = xhr.status;
        if (status === 200) {
            callback(null, xhr.response);
        } else {
            callback(status, xhr.response);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
};
```

> function call:

```
 getJSON('http://localhost:8080/job/'+jobName+'/lastBuild/api/json?tree=timestamp',
        function(err, data) {
            if (err !== null) {
               console.log('Something went wrong: ' + err);
            } else {
                console.log('Your query count: ' + data.query.count);
            }
    });
```

> I am getting 403 error witch indicates for credentials required

Comment: 1. "cardinals"? You meant credentials, right?  2. That is a server-side problem. We cannot help you only with this code.

Comment: yes, thank you for the correction, when I enter the URL in my browser I am getting the JSON data if that helps to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using axios library.

```
var axios = require("axios");

var url = "your-url";

async function getData(url) {
  try {
    var response = await axios.get(url);
    var data = response.data;
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

getData(url);
```

You need to install axios library using:

```
npm install axios --save
```

Comment: I am still getting 403 error, do I need to enter site credentials somewhere?